# adding element into a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, element

How Can i Create an Element  Into a div using javascript
when i make this code:

```
<script>document.createElement('script');<script>
```

It is works but the element created in the document
How i Can Select a Specific   or an #id To The Element Being Created in It
I tried this code

```
<script>var newDivThingy = document.getElementById("mbprogs");
var tag1 = newDivThingy.createElement('script');<script>
```

but without any success

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new `script` element at a specific place in the first place?

Comment: Post the part of your code wich contains the div.

Comment: yeah that what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

It's always `document.createElement`.

For example, `tag1 = document.createElement('script');`

You can then use `newDivThingy.appendChild(tag1);` to add it to `newDivThingy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the element then do the DOM manipulation.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
newDivThingy.appendChild(script);
```

Don't know why you need insert a script element into a div though.

Comment: to select it from this div because i have many javascript <script> in my website